# How to show that if $X = L^1 (\Omega)$, $f(u) = \int_\Omega u(x) dx$ for $u \in X$, then $f \in X^*$ and $\|f\| = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I want to show that if $X = L^1 (\Omega)$, 
$f(u) = \int_\Omega u(x) dx$ for $u \in X$,
then $f \in X^*$ and $\|f\| = 1$

I tried $|f(u)| \le \| u\|_{L^1} $ so that $\|f\| \le 1$.

But how can I prove the other direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have
 $$\|f\| =\sup_{\|u\|=1} \int_\Omega u(x)dx\leq\sup_{\|u\|=1} \|u\|=1.$$

Now, choose $V\subseteq \Omega$ such that $0<m(V)<\infty$. Then $v:=\chi_V/m(V)$ satisfies $\|v\| =1$ and $f(v)=1$, so the upper bound above is achieved.

$$\|f\| =\sup_{\|u\|=1} \int_\Omega u(x)dx\geq \int_\Omega v(x)dx=1.$$

Hence, $\|f\|=1$.

Comment: But i think this does not work for $\Omega$ is not bounded domain

Comment: That's why I chose $V\subset \Omega$. I'm assuming $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$. I don't think this is true for arbitrary measure spaces.

Comment: oh I got it thanks!

Comment: If $\Omega$ is a measure space without a set of positive, finite measure, you have $L^1(\Omega) = \{0\}$. Hence, the functional $f$ has norm zero.